# Displaying the value of a property from a class according to selected item in listbox

Tags: c#, class, listbox

I made a class named product and I added different products to my class in my main program like this:

```
product1 = new Product();
product1.Name = "product1";
product1.Price = 3.50;

Product product2 = new Product();
product2.Name = "product2";
product2.Price = 4;
```

And I've got a listbox which I fill with this method:

```
private void fillProducts(string item)
        {
            lstProducts.Items.Add(item);
        }
```

So when I use the method it would look like this: `fillProducts(product1.Name);`

Now what I want to achieve is that when I press a button (btnConfirm) it would see which product has been selected in the listbox and get the price of the product and display it in a label

```
lblConfirm.Text = "The price of product1 is: " + *the price of product1*;
```

So I need to display the price of product1 in my label and I don't want to use if-statements for every single product because there would be over 200 if-statements. If anything is unclear in this question please tell me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just populate the ListBox with a `Product`, not a string:

```
private void fillProducts(Product item)
{
    lstProducts.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Use properties built-in to the ListBox to tell it what value to display:

```
lstProducts.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

Then access the `SelectedItem` property to get the selected item when you need it:

```
var price = ((Product)lstProducts.SelectedItem).Price

lblConfirm.Text = "The price of product1 is: " + price;
```

Comment: It works but in my listbox it says projectname.Products a bunch of times (once for every product) and when I press the confirm button it shows me the names correctly, do you happen to know what causes this?